# How do I use RegEx if I want to group similar matches inside a match?

Tags: python, regex

I have something that is structured like this:

```
class classname1 extends classname2;
..
..
..
endclass classname1;
```

The regex I am using is: `r"(?<=class )([^\s]+)(.*?)(?=endclass)"`

I am using `matches = re.finditer(regex, <file>, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)` to find all the matches.

This gives me a full match for everything from "classname1" to until it finds the word "endclass" and in group 1, I receive the class name, and in group 2, I receive everything inside.

Now, I am facing issues whenever there is another class inside the classname1. For example:

```
class classname1 extends classname2;
 ..
    class classname3 extends classname4;
     ..
     ..
     ..
    endclass classname3;
 ..
 ..
endclass classname1;
```

How can I fix the regex so that it is smart enough to know to ignore the class and endclass inside? And if it's possible, is it also possible to group the class...endclass that are inside?

Thank you.

Comment: A regex is the wrong tool for this, as a regex doesn't handle unknown levels of nestings well. You may need to build a parser for this.

Comment: @Robert what would you recommend using? Something that is able to stack and collect data? thanks.